# automate generation of lines and y-axes in plotly python

Tags: python, loops, methods, plotly, plotly-python

Disclaimer:

I am trying to learn Python, so if you find the time to answer this question, please explain as much as possible.

I have been trying to make a program that will generate plotly graphs from .csv files but I am struggling with the plotly module. Generating the multiple y-axis using a for loop to be specific.

The data in the csv files can vary greatly (amount of columns, data types etc.)

My main goal is to create a program that generates a graph that looks like this example:

[image]

Shown below is the data for the input file.
I've tried to make it so that pandas formats the input data to the required format.

input file: small_med_lar_num.csv

```
year;col_test_sn;col_test_mn;col_test_ln;col_test_bool_value;col_test_float
2000;1;356;986462;True;0,1
2001;3;567;624964;true;0,2
2002;5;454;529573;False;0,3
2003;4;878;329486;FALSE;5,4
2004;6;343;572057;true;0,5
2005;9;385;824585;TRUE;120,6
2006;7;476;175424;False;0,7
2007;2;754;986386;False;3,8
2008;5;927;476890;true;0,9
2009;5;973;268423;true;1984,01
2010;2;123;723423;true;1,9
```

Here is my attempt on automatically generate the graphical objects needed.
The generation of the traces seems to work fine (but can certainly be optimized)
My problems surfaces when I try to automatically generate multiple y-axises.

If someone can provide a working example on this, I would be very grateful.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# variables:**
column_list = []
df = []
csv_del = ';'
csv_dec = ','
y_axis_number_list = []
plot_title = 'small_medium_large_number_test'
input_csv_file_path = 'small_med_lar_num.csv'

#     Import csv file, declaring the delimiter, decimal and bool values**

df = pd.read_csv(
    input_csv_file_path,
    delimiter=csv_del,
    decimal=csv_dec,
    true_values=['TRUE', 'True', 'true'],
    false_values=['FALSE', 'False', 'false']
)

#     convert True/False to 1/0 in df by defining type as int**

df.replace({False: 0, True: 1}, inplace=True)

#     make list of column names**

column_list = list(df.columns)
print('\n')
print(column_list)
print('\n')

length = len(column_list)
print(length)

#    loop thru amount of columns to generate yaxes numbers**

for temp in range(length):
    if temp <= 1:
        y_axis_number_list.append('y')
    else:
        y_axis_number_list.append(f'y{temp}')
    temp += 1


print(f'y_axis_number_list: {y_axis_number_list}')


#     Create traces**
fig = go.Figure()

#     method for creating traces based on passed arguments**
def new_trace(data_axis, y_axis_n, time_axis=column_list[0]):
    print(f'data_axis: {data_axis}')
    print(f'y_axis#: {y_axis_n}')
    print(f'time_axis: {time_axis}')
    print('\n')

    yaxis = str(y_axis_n)

    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        x=df[time_axis],
        y=df[data_axis],
        mode='lines',
        name=data_axis,
        yaxis=y_axis_n,
    )
    )


#     loop thru column list, omitting time column[0] to generate traces**

for (data_axis, y_axis_n) in zip(column_list[1:], y_axis_number_list[1:]):
    # print (data_akse)
    new_trace(data_axis, y_axis_n, )

# generate Y axis and making them invisible**

fig.update_layout(title=plot_title,  # title of plot
                  plot_bgcolor='rgb(230, 230,230)',  # plot backgroud color
                  showlegend=True,  # show legends on side of plot
                  hovermode='x unified',
                  xaxis=dict(domain=[0.0, .80]  # plot size
                             ),

                  yaxis1=dict(
                      title="",
                      nticks=0,
                      anchor="free",
                      side="left",
                      showticklabels=False,
                  ),
                  yaxis2=dict(
                      title="",
                      anchor="free",
                      overlaying="y",
                      side="left",
                      nticks=0,
                      showticklabels=False,
                  ),
                  yaxis3=dict(
                      title="",
                      anchor="free",
                      overlaying="y",
                      side="left",
                      nticks=0,
                      showticklabels=False,
                  ),
                  yaxis4=dict(
                      title="",
                      anchor="free",
                      overlaying="y",
                      side="left",
                      nticks=0,
                      showticklabels=False,
                  ),
                  yaxis5=dict(
                      title="",
                      anchor="free",
                      overlaying="y",
                      side="left",
                      nticks=0,
                      showticklabels=False,
                  ),
                   yaxis6=dict(
                      title="",
                      anchor="free",
                      overlaying="y",
                      side="left",
                      nticks=0,
                      showticklabels=False,
                  )

                  )

fig.update_xaxes(showgrid=False)
fig.update_yaxes(showgrid=False)

#     SHOW PLOT IN BROWSER**
fig.show()
```

Comment: So, your problem is optimization because your code is working, right?

Comment: what `"problems surfaces when I try to automatically generate multiple y-axises."`? Describe it. Don't expect that we will run code to see problem. (besides it may work correctly on our computers, or we may think that it should work in this way). And we can't read in your mind, You have to describe all details in question (not in comments)